# Need to add an image asset through HTML using src in Flutter web view

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout, dart-pub, flutter-dependencies

Do we need to write the path of the asset from the asset folder or it saves  somewhere else when it generate apk or ipa? Tried with using path from asset but didn't work.

```
String s="<img src="file:///asset/images/test.png" width="42" height="42" align="right">"
```

We are using this as a string and passing it in web view but web view is not showing the image.

Comment: Why are you using html like this in Flutter?

Comment: Good Question. I need to show the static content coming from backend and have to show even if I am not connected to a network. So, I saved html content coming from backend to my local file. This static screen contains an image and I need to take that image that is stored in asset folder to open it in web view. 

Therefore, I make html string containing my image from asset and html content coming from the API and show that in the web view.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @PrakharAnand If I understand you right your building and html file in Flutter to put in a webview? Why not just use https://flutter.io/docs/cookbook/images/network-image in normal Flutter? Edit: Or if you want to do that, just makes PWA?

Comment: @halfer, Thanks for your suggestions. Will look into it

Comment: Work for android but unable to render image in iOS. If you can please help!!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57702924/how-to-render-image-using-html-css-using-flutter-to-create-ios-app

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src=\"file:///android_asset/flutter_assets/assets
```

the above code works for me in with this package -> flutter_inappbrowser
but i think it will work only for android.

Comment: Work for android. What about iOS?

Comment: Work for android but unable to render image in iOS. If you can please help!!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57702924/how-to-render-image-using-html-css-using-flutter-to-create-ios-app

Answer (score -1):

You need to define your images in `pubspec.yaml` file as follows:

```
assets:
      - assets/your_image.png
```

then you can use your images in code using their path.

Comment: Defined this in yaml and even used in ImageAsset in the code and is working but not Getting the image if we provide path to the src tag in html string.

I want to use image in src html tag. Kindly help

Comment: Can you specify whole pubspec.yaml file